# MongoDB leftjoin if an attribute matches with any attribute of the second collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and struggling with the following.

I have 2 collections structured as below:

**Tags collection:**

```js
{
    "_id": "10",
    "assets": [
        {
            "_id": "11",
            "path": "aa.png"
        },
        {
            "_id": "22",
            "path": "gg.png",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "22",
    "assets": [
        {
            "_id": "33",
            "path": "jj.png"
        },
        {
            "_id": "44",
            "path": "kk.png",
        }
    ]
}
```

**Adverts collection:**

```js
{
    "_id": "64",
    "value": "zuzu",
    "default_values": {
        "background_image_1": "aa.png",
        "brand_image": "bb.png",
        "background_image_2": "cc.png",
        "background_image_3": "dd.png",
        "random_image_1": "ee.png"
    }
},
    {
    "_id": "75",
    "value": "gogo",
    "default_values": {
        "background_image_1": "aa.png",
        "background_image_2": "gg.png",
        "background_image_3": "hh.png",
        "background_image_4": "ii.png",
        "background_image_5": "jj.png"
    }
}
```

If "path" has any match with any attribute in `"default_values"`, I need to add the `"value"` to the object as you can see below.

**Expected Result:**

```js
{
    "_id": "10",
    "assets": [
        {
            "_id": "11",
            "path": "aa.png",
            "value": ["zuzu", "gogo"]
        },
        {
            "_id": "22",
            "path": "gg.png",
            "value": ["gogo"]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "22",
    "assets": [
        {
            "_id": "33",
            "path": "jj.png",
            "value": ["gogo"]
        },
        {
            "_id": "44",
            "path": "kk.png",
            "value": []
        }
    ]
}
```

One last thing, I reach to the `Tags` after an aggregate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `asset` needs to be processed individually so you have to start with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html). In the next step you can run [$lookup with custom join condition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) which will combine the data with `Adverts`. The inner pipeline is a bit more complex since you need to run [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) first in order to [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) that array and find matching images. After the lookup stage you need [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to combine your `Tags` based on `_id` value.

```
db.Tags.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$assets"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Adverts",
            let: { path: "$assets.path" },
            pipeline: [
                { 
                    $project: {
                        value: 1, 
                        img: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: { "$objectToArray": "$default_values" },
                                cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.v", "$$path" ] }
                            }
                        } 
                    } 
                },
                { $match: { $expr: { $gt: [ { $size: "$img" }, 0 ] } } },
                { $project: { _id: 0, value: 1 } }
            ],
            as: "value"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            assets: {
                $push: {
                    _id: "$assets._id",
                    path: "$assets.path",
                    value: { $map: { input: "$value", in: "$$this.value" } }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zUtAfT_sKzy)